# VueJS: Best practice for working with global object between components?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

there is `User.js` class and user object(`user = new User();`).

The `user` object is being used in all nested components. in `User` class there are so many important methods.

How can I simply use/access `this.user` or `this.$user` and its methods in any component?

***1-solution*** (temporary working solution): Setting `user` in vuex's **store** and define in all components' `data`:

```
data(){
  return {
    user:this.$store.state.user
  }
}
```

Cons: in every component, this should be added. Note: there are so many components.

***2-solution***: adding user to Vue's **prototype** like plugin:

```
Vue.prototype.$user = user
```

Cons: when `user`'s data changes, it doesn't **effect** in DOM element (UI).

***3-solution***: putting to components's **props**.

Cons: in every component, this should be added. Note: Again there are so many components.

All of the solutions I found have issues, especially as the project gets larger and larger.

Any suggestion and solution will be appreciated!

Comment: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/4029 this will be helpful. read it

Comment: @CodeManiac Thank you, I didn't know react's context-like feature. But I didn't find good solution.

Comment: for this scenario `dependency injection` is the best solution. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Dependency-Injection

Comment: Your code `this.user or this.$user` will also need to write in every components ! No difference . But you have nothing to change `user` data ,just access direct from store

Comment: @ﾃﾞﾋﾞｯﾄ Yes right. Accessing from store in component's template is not good. just want to use something like `{{user.isAdmin()}}`

Comment: @Lahori yes this one is new for me and I tried it. first I provide user and inject it in component, when user info changes by socket or api, it doesnt effect dom element similar to 2-solution

Comment: @imudin07 yes this is because injected values are non-reactive. you need to use this npm package instead https://github.com/LinusBorg/vue-reactive-provide

Comment: @Lahori great! this is very useful package!! I will consider to use if the solution in below answer will have performance issue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Note: Applies for Vue 2x

#### Proposal 1: Using getters from vuex

- You could use `getters` along with `mapGetters` from Vuex to include users within computed properties for each component.

Vuex

```
getters: {
  // ...
  getUser: (state, getters) => {
    return getters.user
  }
}
```

component

```
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'
computed: {
  ...mapGetters([getUser])
}
```

#### Proposal 2: add a watcher via plugin

Vue

```
// When using CommonJS via Browserify or Webpack
const Vue = require('vue')
const UserPlug = require('./user-watcher-plugin')

// Don't forget to call this
Vue.use(UserPlug)
```

user-watcher-plugin.js

```
const UserPlug = {
  install(Vue, options) {
    // We call Vue.mixin() here to inject functionality into all components.

    Vue.watch: 'user'
  }
};

export default UserPlug;
```

#### Proposal 3: add a computed property `user` as plugin via mixin

Vue

```
// When using CommonJS via Browserify or Webpack
const Vue = require('vue')
const UserPlug = require('./user-watcher-plugin')

// Don't forget to call this
Vue.use(UserPlug)
```

user-watcher-plugin.js

```
const UserPlug = {
  install(Vue, options) {
    // We call Vue.mixin() here to inject functionality into all components.

    Vue.mixin({
      computed: {
        user: function() {
          return this.$store.state.user
        }
      }
    })
  }
};

export default UserPlug;
```

Comment: thank you for your time and purposals. 2nd 3rd ones look good! Let me try to implement it

Comment: I used proposal 3, and it worked perfectly. only I am only worrying about the performance

Answer (score 3):

Based on @Denis answer, specifically **Proposal 3**, Here is the `UserPlugin.js`:

```
import store from '@/store/store';
import User from './User';

const UserPlugin = {
  install(Vue) {
    const $user = new User();
    window.$user = $user;
    store.commit('setUser', $user);
    Vue.mixin({
      computed: {
        $user() {
          return store.state.user;
        }
      }
    });
  }
};
export default UserPlugin;
```

and `main.js`:

```
import UserPlugin from './common/UserPlugin';

Vue.use(UserPlugin);

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app');
```

For further usage, I published small library for solving these kinda issues:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-global-var

Answer (score 1):

You can use mixins to add `User.js` to your root component like

```
import userLib from './User';
//User.js path should correct
```

Then

```
var app = new Vue({
    router,
    mixins: [
        userLib
    ],
  //.....
});
```

After that you can use any of these `User` method in your any component like

```
this.$parent.userClassMehtod();
```

or if any data access

```
this.$parent.userClassData;
```

Finally dont forget to add `export default{//..}` in `User.js`

Note:  This is only work if you export all method of `User.js` into `export default`

Comment: Thank you for your solution, however it cant be applied here, I cannot add `User.js` to component directly using mixin. It is es6 class with user info and some methods, we decide UI according to user's attrs and methods. `user= new User()`. here `user.something` should be reactive and accessible in any component's template and script

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't actually use all methods/attributes of `user` in every component, but a subset of them everytime, I don't see any reason why solution 1 & 2 do not work for you, since passing the whole `user` object to every component is not necessary.

Let's say your object `User` have some attributes (a1, a2, a3, etc.) and methods (m1, m2, m3...). If a component only needs some of them (e.g. a1, a2, m1, m2, m3) then with Vuex, you can use mapping functions (mapState, mapGetters, mapMutations and mapActions) to get the exact info from `user`

```
import { mapState, mapGetters, mapMutations, mapActions } from 'vuex'
export default {
    computed: {
        ...mapState('user', [ 'a1' ]),
        ...mapGetters('user', [ 'a2' ])
    },
    methods: {
        ...mapMutations('user', [ 'm1' ]),
        ...mapActions('user', [ 'm2', 'm3' ])
    }
}
```

For solution 2 (using prototype), to make component update when `user` data changes, you can map the necessary data to component via `methods`.

```
export default {
    methods: {
        userA1() {
            return this.$user.attributes.a1;
        },
        userM1() {
            this.$user.methods.m1();
        }
        // and so on
    }
}
```

Even better, you can create mixins to explicitly map data from `user`, and reuse your mixins to avoid duplicated code in components. It can be applied for both Vuex solution and prototype solution.

```
// mixin1:
const mixin1 = {
    computed: {
        ...mapState('user', [ 'a1' ]),
    },
    methods: {
        ...mapMutations('user', [ 'm1' ])
    }
}

// mixin2:
const mixin2 = {
    computed: {
        ...mapGetters('user', [ 'a2' ]),
    },
    methods: {
        ...mapActions('user', [ 'm2', 'm3' ])
    }
}

// component1
export default {
    mixins: [ mixin1 ]
}

// component 2
export default {
    mixins: [ mixin1, mixin2 ]
}
```

But if you really need to pass the whole object `user` to every component, then nothing could do. Rather, you should review your implementation and see if there is any better way to break the object into smaller meaningful ones.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you answer. As I mentioned the 1-solution is working well, but needs to add it for all components. in the solution, I write the least code. Let's assume I use most of the methods of User in every components. Our team found that adding Vuex's the mapping functions for all component one by one seems not good and burden where 1-solution is already burden. 4-solution I have is global mixin, but couldn't make it work

Comment: @imudin07 if that's the case, then my answer seems not relevant to your actual problem. And yes, a global mixin should reduce code duplication in this case; you can make another question for the global mixin if you are still stuck at it. Anw good luck OP.

Answer (score 1):

I just created the minimal [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/rr17267ll4) to clear the idea of how `dependency Injection` works in vue.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I really appreciate it. this solution I will use for some other object which will not be used for all components. But the accepted answer's solution is very suitable for user object which is being used by almost all components(count is around 30-40)

Comment: and `User` is just es6 class with js extension, it is not Vue component

Comment: @imudin07 are they (30-40) all children of parent ?

Comment: yes multiply routes and with components and children of them

Answer (score -3):

You can have a second Vue instance and declare a reactive property.

[See: Reactivity in depth](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties)